# How to create ORM independent generic repository?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository

This is my generic base repository ( part of it) - using EntityFramework 6(yes EF6 does have a generic repository but there are so many conflicting opinions on the net whether to still use repository pattern or not that I'm going with repository for now)

```
 public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T: class
    {
        private BlueWhaleEntities _dbContext;
        public BlueWhaleEntities DbContext { get; set; }
        public BaseRepository(BlueWhaleEntities dbContext )
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;         
        }
//...More Add,Remove Generic Methods
```

and I have a more specific `PersonRespository`

```
class PersonRepository: BaseRepository<Person>
    {
        public PersonRepository(BlueWhaleEntities blueWhaleEntities) : base(blueWhaleEntities)
        {
             //...Add,Remove methods for Person which override Generic repository's methods 
        }
    }
```

But looking at this, one purpose of the repository was that I could change ORMs..but I'm injecting the EntityFramework DataContext in the constructor, tying me to EF.

So what do I inject in the constructor instead then that I can change the ORM to something else ( very unlikely but theoretically) later on if needed?

Thank you

Comment: the "so I can change ORM's"  is almost always over-design.

Comment: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling/

Answer (score 2):

Different ORMs have very different APIs. EF requires DbContext, NHibernate requires Session, Dapper requires plain DbConnection, MongoDB has MongoDatabase. So, there should not be some base class which will fit any possible API of different ORMs. You even can switch from ORM to plain ADO if you will need best performance. Actually sometimes you even can store objects in-memory.

What you should have is *interfaces* which will be implemented for different ORMs

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T GetById(object id);
    void Add(T entity);
    // ...
}

public interface IPersonRepository : IRepository<Person>
{
    IEnumerable<Person> GetPeopleByDepartment(int id);
}
```

Their purpose is hiding implementation details from your application. Depend on these interfaces. Create different implementations. I usually move repository implementations to separate assembly, which has name like *Foo.Persistence.EF* or *Foo.Persistence.NHibernate*. If I need different implementation, I just switch persistence assembly.

Comment: So repositories aren't really abstracting the ORM then are they. Because this clearly means one person repository PER ORM type, which means if you have to change ORM you have to change every single repository. That defeats the purpose of repository doesnt it? Or am I missing something here :)

Comment: @iAteABug_And_iLiked_it exactly. Repository should have different implementation for different ORM. There is no other way. Well, except moving all implementations in single monster class. Good news - you will switch implementations very rarely (I did this two times in 6 years). And that does not defeats the purpose of repository. Purpose of repository - hide data access implementation details from client. It should not allow to use any implementation you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very clear solution for this problem. You should seperate PersonRepository implementations. As a result you need to ORM independent IPersonRepository interface. And you can inherit from this interface for any ORM specific implementation.

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    public TEntity Add(TEntity entity);
    //get T,
    //...
}
```

```
public interface EFRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext> : IRepository<TEntity>
{
    public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        using var context = new TContext();
        var addedEntity = context.Entry(entity);
        addedEntity.State = EntityState.Added;
        context.SaveChanges();
        return entity;
    }
  //get T,
  //...
}
```

You should keep generic IRepository and generic EfRepositoryBase in like **Common** namespace.

```
public interface IPersonRepository : IRepository<Person>
{
}
```

```
public interface EfPersonRepository : EfRepositoryBase<Person, MyDbContext> IRepository<Person>
{
}
```

```
public interface MyOrmPersonRepository : IRepository<Person>
{
    public Person Add(Person p)
    {
        // MyOrm specific codes...
    }

    //get Person,
    //...
}
```

You should keep PersonRepository, EfPersonRepository and MyOrmPersonRepository in like **Repositories** namespace.

```
public class PersonService
{
    IPersonRepository _personRepository;
    
    public Client(IPersonRepository personRepository)
    {
        _personRepository = personRepository;
    }

    public void AddPerson(Person p)
    {
        //business, validations, logging etc.
        //...
        _personRepository.Add(p);
    }
}
```

```
public class Client
{
    //...
    void Main()
    {
        //You should use DI tool in here
        
        PersonService personService = new PersonService(new EfPersonRepository());
        //or
        PersonService personService2 = new PersonService(new MyOrmPersonRepository());
        
        personService.AddPerson(new Person());
        //or
        personService2.AddPerson(new Person());

        //...
    }
}
```

You can check this [project](https://github.com/tolgacakir/TaskManagerApp-NetCore) for more information about this architectural design